# Pass attributes between modules

Tags: python

Good evening! I have a "MainWindow" form where the user information is loaded. The point is that this information requires many processes and analysis and I don't want to load the main windows module with so much code, but I would like to carry out the processes in another module and that module loads the labels that the main windows has.
I don't know how to do it, it occurred to me to import the views also in the module where the processes are going to be carried out, so that they can refer to the mainwindows labels.
The MainWindows code:

```
class MainWindows_Controller(QMainWindow, MainWindow_UI):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.setupUi(self)
    self.mouseMoveEvent=self.mover_ventana
    self.stackedWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
```

he code of the views whose name is "MainWindow_UI" is:

```
class MainWindow_UI(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow_UI):
    if not MainWindow_UI.objectName():
        MainWindow_UI.setObjectName(u"MainWindow_UI")
    self.Frame_Top_Menu.setFrameShape(QFrame.StyledPanel)
    self.Frame_Top_Menu.setFrameShadow(QFrame.Raised)
    self.horizontalLayout = QHBoxLayout(self.Frame_Top_Menu)
    self.horizontalLayout.setSpacing(0)
    self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName(u"horizontalLayout")
    self.horizontalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
    self.label = QLabel(self.Frame_Top_Menu)
    self.label.setObjectName(u"label")
    self.label.setMinimumSize(QSize(250, 40))
```

I add only a portion of the code so that it does not become so extensive, the point is that I thought of creating a new module called "Processes" for example, where I import the MainWindow_UI to be able to reference the Labels created, but then that module "Processes" I must import it in MainWindows_Controller to be able to call the methods, it would be something like this:

```
import MainWindow_UI    

class Procesos(object,MainWindow_UI):

def setupUi(self, MainWindow_UI):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()


    def Rellenar_Labels()
         pass
```

Could you tell me if that way of doing it is correct or if there is a more efficient way please.